Calculation of Hilbert symbol over $\Bbb Q_p$ where $p$ is an odd prime
Let $a,b\in \Bbb Q$ be rationals and $p$ an odd prime. I want to calculate the Hilbert symbol $(a,b)_p$. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_symbol#Hilbert_symbols_over_the_rationals, we can calculate $(a,b)_p$ as follows: write $a=p^\alpha u$ and $b=p^\beta v$ where $u,v$ are integers coprime to $p$. Then $$(a,b)_p= (-1)^{\alpha \beta (p-1)/2} \left(\dfrac{u}{p}\right)^\beta \left(\dfrac{v}{p}\right)^\alpha. $$
What I am curious about is: how can we write $a=p^\alpha u$ where $u$ is an integer coprime to $p$? For example if $a=\frac{1}{2}$ and $p=3$, what are $\alpha$ and $u$? Are they uniquely determined?
P.S. However we may assume that $a,b$ are integers: if $a=r/s$ then $(rs,b)_p=(as^2,b)_p=(a,b)_p\cdot (s^2,b)_p=(a,b)_p$ because $s^2$ is a square.  In the case that $a,b$ are integers, I can see that we can write $a=p^\alpha u$ uniquely with $\alpha, u$ are integers and $(u,p)=1$.

If you read that section it says "over the $p$-adics..." so $u, v$ are not meant to be integers but $p$-adic integers. If $a = \frac{1}{2}$ and $p = 3$ then $\alpha = 0$ and $u = \frac{1}{2}$.
In general $\alpha = \nu_p(a)$ is the $p$-adic valuation; this uniquely determines $\alpha$ and $u$, and gives that $u = \frac{\alpha}{p^{\nu_p(\alpha)}} \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ is a $p$-adic unit.

Thanks. Is it correct that if $a$ is an integer then $\alpha$ and $u$ satisfying $p^\alpha u = a $ are determined by the prime factorization of $a$?

@user302934: yes, that's right.
